# How to resolve GIT conflict if I forgot to push the commits and created a feature branch from my local develop branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-merge-conflict

I'm looking for an easy way to resolve my current git conflict.

This it how it happened:

1. local commits (5) created on my develop branch (without pushing them)
2. feature branch created from my local develop branch
3. feature branch development finished, commits have been pushed
4. PULL request from feature branch to develop merged
5. Now I checked out my local develop branch and when I tried to sync I saw that there are already incoming and outgoing commits too, now I realized that I forgot to push them earlier and guessed I'm having a trouble...
6. (tried to sync but not surprisingly it has a lot of conflicts)

I hope it's understandable and someone could help me, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not made any new commits on your local `develop` branch since you have created the `feature` branch (`feature` branch that was pushed, and then merged to the remote `origin/develop` branch), you could simply:

- fetch from `origin`
- reset your current `develop` branch to `origin/develop`

(I would save, for the above scenario or the one below, your local repository in a duplicate folder, just in case something foes wrong)

---

That would work since `origin/develop` does include your local `develop`+`feature` work, merged through the pull request to `origin/develop`.

If you had done commits on develop since the creation of feature, you can rebase those new commits on top of `origin/develop`

```
git fetch origin
git branch tmp origin/develop
git rebase --onto tmp $(git merge-base feature develop) develop
git branch -f develop tmp
git switch develop
```

Comment: @Mitulátbáti Well done! Which scenario did you follow?

Comment: I reset the develop branch to the commit that was last pushed. For my luck VS had it built in so I just had to do one click.